# Materialized path and SQL query explaination

Tags: mysql, sql, tree

i am reading this article about saving trees into database 
http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_sql_patterns_trees.htm
But i don't understand for example this

```
select e1.ename from emp e1, emp e2
where e1.path like e2.path || '%'
and e2.ename = 'JONES'
```

What does mean  this: `e1.path like e2.path || '%'`

I don't understand using boolean operator in that query. I know '%' is (.*) in reqular expression. Its looks for me like: `(e1.path == e2.path) or (e1.path == whateverIWant)`.
Thx for hlp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%` is a wildcard in a SQL like expression, so it means `e1.path` should start with `e2.path`.

`e1.path` is therefore a child of `e2.path`.

This query retrieves all the subordinates of employee `JONES`.

Comment: Can you pleas post some url, where it is explained? I know what is for example "like k%" and what is wildcard. But i dont understand that expression "like something ||(or?) '%'

Comment: The `||` is a common concatenation operator in databases (but not MySQL). So, instead of `e2.Path || '%'`, do `CONCAT(e2.Path, '%')`.